beanstalk docker - how to set container name with Docker.run.json v1
I'm deploying this Docker.run.json file and its working.
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myproject:build-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": 80,
            "HostPort": 80
        }
    ]
}

Now I need to create a cron with .ebextensions to run a command inside my container.
The problem is the container is always run with random names.
Is there any way to define the container name so I can run command inside it?
docker exec MY_CONTAINER echo "Hello world"


You can dynamically get the name and exec your command:
docker exec $(docker ps --filter "ancestor=xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myproject" --format "{{.Names}}") echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1

ancestor=IMAGE_NAME: This filter selects containers that were created from a specific image, which will be static, so you can use it without any issue
